# Apps Script debugging

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I am trying to write a simple apps script, and keep getting this error:

> message ReferenceError: spreadsheetapp is not defined (line 2)

How do I fix this?

I am trying to have the app display the sheet name using this script:

```
function GetSheetName() {return spreasheetapp.getactivespreadsheet().getactivesheet().getName();}
```

Comment: Which line is line 2? There is only 1 line.

Comment: Are you sure that the error message says "spreadsheetapp" and not "spreasheetapp"? Because the code says "spreasheetapp" which is inconsistent with the error message you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

About your following script,

```js
spreasheetapp.getactivespreadsheet().getactivesheet().getName()
```

- `spreasheetapp` is required to be `SpreadsheetApp`.
- `getactivespreadsheet()` is required to be `getActiveSpreadsheet()`.
- `getactivesheet()` is required to be `getActiveSheet()`.

Please use the Class name and method name with the camel case. When these are reflected in your script, please modify as follows.

```js
function GetSheetName() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
}
```

And, in this case, the following modification can be also used.

```js
function GetSheetName() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
}
```

#### References:

- [Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)
- [getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet)